# PHP Session variables not being passed while using angular 5

Tags: php, angular

I am developing an Angular 5 app with PHP back-end, where the user must login to access a different component. I am using using Wamp, and the following is my login.php page:

```
<?php
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    error_log("Not started");
    session_start();
}
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

require_once ('./DBConnect.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db ,$port);

$regUserData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
$response = array();
$email = $regUserData['email'];
$pass = $regUserData['password'];
$pass = md5($pass);

if($email ===''||$pass ===''){
    $response['success'] = FALSE;
    $response['msg'] = 'Please fill all fields';
}
else{
    $query1 = "select * from user where Email = '".$email."'";
    $result1 = $conn->query($query1);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)===0){
        $response['success'] = FALSE;
        $response['msg'] = 'User does not exist';
    }
    else{
        $query2 = "select * from user where Email = '".$email."' and Password = '".$pass."'";
        $result2 = $conn->query($query2);
        $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)===0){
            $response['success'] = FALSE;
            $response['msg'] = 'Email or password incorrect';
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['Id'] = $row1['Id'];
            $response['success'] = true;
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

The 2 header statements are used because wamp is on different port than my Angular app. This login.php page is working fine but when I try to pass the session variable to another php page I get errors in the error_log file that the 'Id' variable is undefined. This is my second php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

require_once ('./DBConnect.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db ,$port);
error_log($_SESSION['Id']); //The error is on this line

$query = "select * from Service";
$result = $conn -> query($query);
$arraySingle = array();
$arrayAll = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arraySingle = array(
        'Name' => $row['Name'],
        'Desc' => $row['Description']
    );
    $arrayAll[] = $arraySingle;
}
echo json_encode($arrayAll);
```

The error that I get is :

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Id in C:\wamp64\www\ProjetErgonomie\GetServices.php on line 8

Can someone please help me with my issue? Thanks!!

Comment: can u show the result of pr($_SESSION)

Comment: just show how you are fetching the session value ?

Comment: @lakshay it shows Array([Id] => 8)

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo in the second page I am using error_log to print the value of $_Session['Id'] in the error_log file

Comment: can you show the related code here .

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo can you please tell me what code should I post? My problem is that my session variables are not carried in all the php pages despite the fact that all of them are on the same server (wamp)

Comment: I am saying where you getting the error show me that code and just clear one thing all the pages means the project is running under one server only right ?

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo I commented the line in my 2nd page where I get the error and I added what the error is. And Yes all the PHP pages are on my local Wamp webserver (localhost) and in the same directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170595/discussion-between-roynasr-and-bibhudatta-sahoo).